# Como acceder a las variables globales en python

Tags: python, variables

este proyecto lo vengo desarrollando desde hace un tiempo, solo que lo tenia en un solo archivo y al modularizarlo me surgieron problemas al compilar del tipo "global name 'archivo' is not define ", donde archivo es una variable global. Tengo un archivo "main" el cual es el siguiente:

```
#Laberinto.py

#---------------------------IMPORTACION DE LIBRERIAS------------------------------------
from Clases import Jugador 
from Clases import Camino
from Clases import Arbol
from Funciones import cargarArchivo
from Funciones import cargarLaberinto
from Funciones import MazeRunner
#-------------------------FIN IMPORTACION DE LIBRERIAS----------------------    
#---------------------------INICIALIZACION DE VARIABLES GLOBALES----------
arbol = Arbol(60,120)
nodoPadre = arbol.listaNodos [0]
ancho = 0
alto = 0
laberinto = []#matriz de 1's y 0's que definen al laberinto
mapaConocido = []
archivo = open( "file/matriz.txt", "r" )#archivo que contiene la informacion del laberinto
listaMuros = []#lista de todos los muros con su posicion
listaCamino = []
listaVisitados = []
#-------------------------FIN INICIALIZACION DE VARIABLES GLOBALES-----------------------------------

def main(ancho,alto):
    cargarArchivo(archivo,laberinto,mapaConocido)
    alto,ancho = cargarLaberinto(laberinto,listaCamino,listaMuros,ancho,alto)   
    jugador = Jugador(ancho,alto)
    MazeRunner(jugador,listaCamino,listaMuros,listaVisitados,ancho,alto,mapaConocido,arbol,nodoPadre)

main(ancho,alto)
```

El error anterior lo sortee pasando a cada función las variables globales que va a utilizar pero como algunas funciones mandan llamar a otras dentro de su procedimiento, a estas también les paso las variables que van a ocupar y se me hace un embrollo el pasar tantas variables si están definidas en el archivo principal como globales (No con la palabra global sino fuera de cualquier función) y no poder modificarlas desde cada función sin pasarlas como parámetro. Esto si lo hacían las funciones si estaban en un mismo archivo, pero quise hacerlo mas modularizado. Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de que las funciones en módulos independientes accedan a esas variables globales sin pasarlas como parámetro o sólo lo pueden hacer estando en el mismo módulo donde se definieron las variables?

Aquí agrego el código de otro de los módulos (cargarArchivo):

```
#cargarArchivo.py
def cargarArchivo(archivo,laberinto,mapaConocido):#Funcion que lee el archivo txt   con la forma del laberinto
    for line in archivo.readlines():
        fila = list(line)
        fila.pop()

        while fila.count(',') != 0: #busca y retira las comas en la lista
            fila.remove(',')

        print fila      
        laberinto.append( fila )
        mapaConocido.append( fila )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a partir primero dejando claro que el abuso de variables globales (otro tema son las "constantes") es en principio una mala práctica, peligroso en algunos casos llevando a efectos colaterales inesperados, además de hacer el código innecesariamente menos legible y contribuyendo al conocido como *spaghetti code*.

En mi opinión, no tiene mucho sentido usar variables globales compartidas entre módulos solo porque queremos ahorrarnos el escribir los argumentos al llamar a una función, la justificación del uso de una variable global debería ir más lejos que eso. Incluso yendo un paso más,  funciones como `cargarArchivo` deberían manejar ellas mismas la apertura y el cierre correcto del archivo y retornar las listas, no modificar in situ las listas que les llegan usando un  archivo abierto fuera de la función, dejando en el aire dónde y como se cierra ese archivo o dónde está situado el cursor en un momento dado.

Esto puede parecer que no tiene mucha importancia, pero la tiene y mucha. En un proyecto medianamente grande (e independientemente de los bugs que se pueden ocasionar) usar este tipo de patrones hace que alguien se acuerde de ti y no para bien cuando le toca mantener ese código, incluso uno mismo cuando pasado un tiempo revisa su propio código termina arrepintiéndose.

Dicho esto lo que quieres se puede hacer pero teniendo en cuanta que:

> Las variables globales en Python son **globales con respecto al módulo** en las que se declaran, no con respecto a todo el proceso.

Esto significa que si tenemos:

- ***funciones.py***:

  ```
  def foo():
      global cad
      print(cad)
  ```
- ***main.py***:

  ```
  import funciones

  cad = "Hola"
  funciones.foo()
  ```

Tendremos un error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\main.py", line 4, in <module>
>     funciones.foo()
>   File "D:\funciones.py", line 3, in foo
>     print(cad)
> NameError: name 'cad' is not defined
> ```

`cad` es global en *main.py* pero no lo es en *funciones.py*. ¿Se puede conseguir que`funciones.foo` acceda a la misma sin pasarla como argumento (que repito, es lo normal)? La respuesta es si, lo es y de diferentes formas. Por ejemplo:

- Usar `módulo.variable` para asignar (y en este caso definir) la variable en el propio `funciones.py` desde `main.py`:

  ```
  import funciones

  cad = "Hola"
  funciones.cad = cad
  funciones.foo()
  ```

  Muy bonito, pero `cad` es un objeto inmutable porque es una cadena, si se nos ocurre modificar `cad` después podemos llevarnos una sorpresa:

  ```
  >>> cad = "Adios"
  >>> funciones.foo()
  'Hola'
  ```
- Usar un tercer módulo para compartir las variables globales que sea importado por todos aquellos que las compartan:

  - ***globales.py***:

    ```
    cad = "Hola"
    ```
  - ***funciones.py***:

    ```
    import globales

    def foo():
        print(globales.cad)
    ```
  - ***main.py***:

    ```
    import funciones
    import globales


    funciones.foo() # 'Hola'
    globales.cad = "Adios"
    funciones.foo() # 'Adios'
    ```

El remedio es peor que la enfermedad, no debemos tender a hacer globales variables que estrictamente no lo requieran (hay casos en las que son necesarias y justificado su uso, sobretodo en el caso de constantes), la tendencia debe ser la inversa. Como dice el zen de Python:

> Los espacios de nombres son una gran idea ¡hay que hacer más de eso!

---

Un par de observaciones:

- Usa siempre `global variable` en las funciones que usen una variable global, incluso aunque sean objetos mutables como lo son las listas de tu ejemplo.
- Nunca uses `readlines` a no ser que quieras una lista con las líneas del fichero para ser usada directamente. En los demás casos es muy ineficiente e innecesaria. En tu función `cargarArchivo` es más simple y eficiente hacer:

  ```
  for line in archivo:
      fila = list(line.rstrip().replace(",", ""))
      print fila
  ```

  o si tus líneas son de la forma "`a,b,c,d,e`" (un solo carácter separado por comas):

  ```
  for line in archivo:
      fila = line.rstrip().split(",")
      print fila
  ```

Answer (score 1):

En python las variables globales dentro de una función son de solo lectura, si quieres modificarlas necesitas indicarlo con la palabra reservada "**global**" como en este ejemplo:

```
x = 'Soy global'

def unaFuncion():
    print x

def otraFuncion():
    global x
    x = 'Me han modificado'
    print x

unaFuncion()
otraFuncion()

print x  # La variable "x" en este punto tiene el valor modificado
```

El ejemplo anterior devolverá las siguientes cadenas:

> Soy global
>
> Me han modificado
>
> Me han modificado

Como se puede apreciar si solo quieres obtener su valor no necesitas indicar que accedes a una variable global mientras que para modificar su valor si tienes que hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo:

**fichero: const.py**

IVA = 0.21

**fichero: main.py**

from const import IVA

precio = 40

precioFinal = precio * (1 + IVA)

print(precioFinal)