# Función espejo para carácteres en Python

Tags: python, spyder

quería hacer una función espejo pero no se muy bien como hacerla.
Tengo los siguientes carácteres y debajo de ellos, en orden invertido:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', ... , 'z'
'z', 'y', 'x', ... , 'a'
```

La función que quiero hacer consiste en dar un carácter c y que me devuelva el correspondiente carácter de la fila invertida. Es decir, `espejo('c')` daría de resultado `'x'`, `espejo('a')` daría `'z'`.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda! Gracias a todos!

Comment: Se una forma, pero lo correcto sería que la hicieras por ti mism@. Posiblemente usar la función `zip` te sirva (https://likegeeks.com/es/funcion-zip-de-python/). Que haz intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: También te puede servir el metodo `abecedario.index(letra)` que te devuelve la posición de la letra especificada en `abecedario`. Mezcla eso con algo de matematica y listo!

Comment: No dices qué dificultad tienes. Al menos el código que has intentando. La solución podría ser `s[-s.index(c)-1]`, pero puede ser que no sea lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 4):

La solución más simple es usar un diccionario donde la llave sea la letra "normal" y el valor la letra "espejo":

```
dicc = dict(a='z', b='x', c='y')

for letra in 'abc':
    print(letra, dicc[letra])
```

produce:

```
a z
b x
c y
```

Nota: Lo hice sólo con tres letras para evitarme tanto escribir.

**Edición**

Una versión aún más corta con lambda:

```
espejo = lambda x : chr(ord('z') - ord(x) + ord('a'))
for i in 'abc':
    print(i, espejo(i))
```

produce el resultado deseado.

La función `ord` retorna el valor ASCII del caracter y la función `chr` es el inverso: dado un valor ASCII, devuelve el caracter.

Dado que `ord('z') + ord('a')` es una constante, la puedo reducir a su valor y reemplazarlos en el lambda:

```
espejo = lambda x : chr(219 - ord(x))
```

Comment: Para evitarte tanto escribir: `dicc = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, reversed(string.ascii_lowercase)))`  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Una idea es que en una variable guardes todo los caracteres del abecedario, lo inviertes lo guardas en otra y utilizas la funcion index de str.

```
abecedario = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz"
abecedario_invertido = abecedario[::-1]

def espejo(c):
    return abecedario_invertido[abecedario.index(c)]
```

Otra forma solo tienes que hacer `-1 -str.index(caracter) en abecedario` asi te ahorras lo de invertirlo, esto para que empiece del final y se vaya moviendo hacia la izquierda

Comment: Esta podría ser la mejor respuesta excepto porque estás declarando variables globales innecesariamente. Las [buenas practicas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/154873/80870) dicen que se deben evitar globales a menos que sea estrictamente necesario.

Answer (score 0):

Después de leer todas las respuestas que me fueron de gran utilidad, conseguí programar una función que me hiciera exactamente lo que me pedía el enunciado. Aquí dejo el código por si a alguien le es de utilidad. Gracias a todos!

```
def espejo(c):
   valor = ord(c)
   if valor >= ord('a') and valor <= ord('z'):
       valor = ord(c)
       resta = ord('z') - valor
       espejo = ord('a') + resta
       espejo_caracter = chr(espejo)
   else:
       return c
   return espejo_caracter
```